# typedef + pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

I get an error when initializing a typedef-ed pointer to a member function.
Is it because it is typedef-ed before classs declaration? If so, how can I forward declare the typedef so it can be used inside of struct Definition which is then used inside of the B class itself.

Header file:

```
typedef void (B::* p)()

struct Definition {
   p code = nullptr;
    void execute() {
        code();
    }
}

class B
{

private:
    void semicolon();
    p o;
    void (B::* pointer)();
    std::list<Definition> definitions;
    void definePrimitives();
}
```

**Source file:**

```
void B::definePrimitives() {    
    o= B::semicolon;// error: expression must be a modifiable l-value   
    pointer =&B::semicolon;//works
}
```

Comment: What is A?  what is CScriptEngine? can you sue `std::function`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your error messages obviously have nothing to do with posted code.

Comment: I have updated the source code.  @IlBeldus I have no constraints on what to use. I've only tried the C++11 'using' instead of typedef.

Comment: @Rafal `CScriptEngine` and `A` are still there

Comment: @IlBeldus;please forgive. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
class B;
typedef void (B::* p)();

struct Definition {
    void execute() {
        p();
    }
};

class B
{

private:
    void semicolon();
    p o;
    void (B::* pointer)();
    std::list<Definition> definitions;
    void definePrimitives() {
        o= &B::semicolon;
        pointer =&B::semicolon;
    }
};
```

Basically you have to take the pointer to the function, not the function itself

Comment: please check my updated question. I missed the & in line" pointer =&B::semicolon;" that's what I had in my code. Updated few seconds before your answer. In the case  of " o= &B::semicolon;" the error persists. Visual Studio 2017; c++ standard set to lastest (c++17)

Comment: Alternatively you can use `std::function` with `using p = std::function<void(B*)>;`

Comment: It stroke me that the error can't be reproduced on another compiler. I will look more into this and get back

Comment: what does the line `p();` do?

Comment: @W.F ofcourse it would be pointless in the version I posted. I've updated my code to better reflect my real scenario. code() exectues a given function. The entire thing is to be a Forth compiler. some of the functions are hardcoded in C++ for performance.

Comment: the isolated case compiles on VC++ as well, well, seems like something else is going on here. so thank you all for now.

Answer (score 0):

The code had a couple of problems:
1) it lacked forward declaration of class B as pointed out by IlBeldus.
If you remove forward declaration of class B you will be able to reproduce the error.
2) the execute method inside of Definition struct was wrong. It should be:

```
  struct Definition {
    Code   code = nullptr;
    void execute(B b) {
        b.o = &B::semicolon;
        (b.*(b.c))();
    }
};
```

in my real application I've defined pointer to B to as a member of Definition.
One can't just execute member function by

```
p(); or code();
```

one needs to specify the object of type B first, like in my example above:

```
(b.*(b.c))();
```

3) Thirdly, my code required struct **Definition** to be declared ***below*** B, and struct **Definition** had to be forward-declared before B. just like this:

**header file:**

```
 #include <list>
class B;
using Code = void(B::*)(void);

struct Definition;

class B
{

private:

    void (B::* pointer)();
std::list<Definition> definitions;
    void definePrimitives();
public:
    void semicolon();
    Code o = nullptr;
    Code c = nullptr;
};

struct Definition {
    Code   code = nullptr;
    void execute(B b) {
        b.o = &B::semicolon;
        (b.*(b.c))();
    }
};
```

**and source file:**

```
 #include "Header.h"
    #include <list>

    void B::semicolon()
    {
    }

    void B::definePrimitives() {
        o = &B::semicolon;
        pointer = &B::semicolon;
    }

    int main() {
        B b;
        return 0;
    }
```

4) and.. in the C++ world one my want to use classes instead of structs all the way, and since we are past c++11 already one might want to use the **using** clause, instead of typedef.